# Flutter - return a list of different widget types from a list of maps

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var contents = [
    {
      'chapter': 'Chapter 1',
      'pages': [
        'Introduction',
        'The Universal Seal',
        'Vision',
        'Mission',
        'Goals',
        'Core Values',
        'Trust and Priorities of the Office of Student Affairs and Services'
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I am making a drawer with a ListView that contains Text and ListTile widgets. Lest say 'chapter' should be only Text widgets and 'pages' should be ListTile. How do I do this without hard coding the widgets?

Comment: Here is how I would do it: map the json data to meaningful objects(Book, Chapter, Pages), then map those to flutter Widgets(BookPage, ChapterTile, PageView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a builder for each part of your drawer (Header, Tiles, ...) and map over contents to build them.

```
Widget _buildDrawerHeader(String text) {
  return Text(text);
}

List<Widget> _buildListTiles(List<String> pages) {
  return pages.map((page) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(page),
    );
  }).toList();
}

List<Widget> _buildDrawerSection(Map<String, Object> section) {
  return [
    _buildDrawerHeader(section['chapter']),
    ..._buildListTiles(section['pages'])
  ];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: contents
            .map((content) => _buildDrawerSection(content))
            .expand((list) => list)
            .toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make your `contents` array type-safe for easier data handling. Something like this:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> contents = [
  {
    'chapter': 'Chapter 1',
    'pages': [
      'Introduction',
      'The Universal Seal',
      'Vision',
      'Mission',
      'Goals',
      'Core Values',
      'Trust and Priorities of the Office of Student Affairs and Services'
    ]
  }
];
```

After that, you can do the data handling to display it (avoid build-in methods like `forEach()` or `map()` for the UI, they make it hard to debug and imply potential bugs):

```dart
// Generate a list of widget from the contents array
Container(
    child: Column(
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        contents.length,
        (i) => _buildChapter(contents[i]),
      ),
    ),
  )

// Build each chapter with the given map
Widget _buildChapter(Map<String, dynamic> chapter) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(chapter['chapter']),
        ...List<Widget>.generate(chapter['pages'].length,
            (j) => ListTile(title: chapter['pages'][j]))
      ],
    );
  }
```

While this is quick and convenient, as a good practice I recommend using an object `Chapter` to represent your `contents` item. This would make it very intuitive and easier for maintenance later, since using Map directly usually implies potential bugs an also not practical for complicated structure:

```dart
class Chapter {
    Chapter({
        this.chapter,
        this.pages,
    });

    String chapter;
    List<String> pages;

    factory Chapter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Chapter(
        chapter: json["chapter"],
        pages: List<String>.from(json["pages"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "chapter": chapter,
        "pages": List<dynamic>.from(pages.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

The class can now be used as:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Chapter> chapters =
        List<Chapter>.from(contents.map((item) => Chapter.fromJson(item)));
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          chapters.length,
          (i) => _buildChapter(chapters[i]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // The value can be easily access like here
  Widget _buildChapter(Chapter chapter) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(chapter.chapter),
        ...List<Widget>.generate(chapter.pages.length,
            (j) => ListTile(title: Text(chapter.pages[j])))
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your content Map should be like this

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> contents = [
    {
      'chapter': 'Chapter 1',
      'pages': [
        'Introduction',
        'The Universal Seal',
        'Vision',
        'Mission',
        'Goals',
        'Core Values',
        'Trust and Priorities of the Office of Student Affairs and Services'
      ]
    },
    {
      'chapter': 'Chapter 1',
      'pages': [
        'Introduction',
        'The Universal Seal',
        'Vision',
        'Mission',
        'Goals',
        'Core Values',
        'Trust and Priorities of the Office of Student Affairs and Services'
      ]
    }
  ];
```

code for generating widget list

```
List<Widget> widgetList = [];
     contents.forEach((content) {
       content.forEach((key, value) {
         if (key == 'chapter') {
           widgetList.add(Text(value));
         }
         else if (key == 'pages') {
           value.forEach((page){
             widgetList.add(ListTile(title: Text(page),));
           });
         }});
     });
```